# Trouble with SQL statement for count(*)

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I am using SQL Data Server created in Visual Studio 2010.I want to see number of users with some username.

```
var x = from u in db.UserInfoes
                        where
                        u.Password == password &&
                        u.Username == username
                        select count(*);
```

My problem is count(*).VS doesnt accept this.Is there a way to write this?

Answer (score 4):

You could also do it this way:

```
var x = db.UserInfoes
    .Count(u => u.Password == password && u.Username == username);
```

The where clause can be seen of as redundant, as you can put your filter(the predicate) right inside the Count() method

**But since you are checking for a SINGLE record** (assuming only one user matches a username and password combo) You actually want to use the ANY method and get a Boolean

```
var x = db.UserInfoes
    .Any(u => u.Password == password && u.Username == username);
```

Any will be slightly faster than count, as it will return true as soon as it finds a match, instead of going through the entire table to ensure an exact count.

Answer (score 3):

You have to count on returned collection.

```
var x = (from u in db.UserInfoes
         where u.Password == password &&
               u.Username == username
         select u).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Actully you can set up predicate in Count extension:

```
   var x = db.UserInfoes.Count(u => u.Password == password && u.Username == username)
```

Answer (score 1):

using extension method,

```
var x = db.UserInfoes
          .Where(u => u.Password == password && u.Username == username)
          .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = from u in db.UserInfoes
        where u.Password == password &&
              u.Username == username
        select u;
```

Use

```
int i = (x != null) ? x.Count() : 0;
```